# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling when notifydatasetChanged()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

For calling API after creating the activity, I need to perform click event for RecyclerView item of " 0 " index.

for that in onBindviewHolder I'm calling holder.view.performClick event. But the Problem is I need to call a notifydataSetChanged() method in onClick event to update the adapter. Initially, it will auto click on position "0" and calling notifydataSetChanged() method and crashing.
What is the solution for this problem? kindly help.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (position==0){
        holder.itemView.performClick();
    }
```

I'm calling this interface in MainActivity.class

```
public void onRecyclerViewItemClick(@NonNull View view, @NonNull CalendarDTO calendarDTO, int position) {
    isClickedPosition=position;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Toast.makeText(this, calendarDTO.getDate(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

please check the error:-

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: in.playin.calendarrecyclerview, PID: 4063
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.assertNotInLayoutOrScroll(RecyclerView.java:2575)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$RecyclerViewDataObserver.onChanged(RecyclerView.java:4932)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$AdapterDataObservable.notifyChanged(RecyclerView.java:11359)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(RecyclerView.java:6636)
    at in.playin.calendarrecyclerview.CalendarRecyclerViewAdapter$ViewHolder$1.onClick(CalendarRecyclerViewAdapter.java:115)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
    at in.playin.calendarrecyclerview.CalendarRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CalendarRecyclerViewAdapter.java:59)
    at in.playin.calendarrecyclerview.CalendarRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CalendarRecyclerViewAdapter.java:22)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6356)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6389)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5335)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5598)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3025)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5955)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5955)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5955)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5955)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5955)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2112)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1228)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1464)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1119)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6060)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
```

Comment: stack trace please.

Comment: Please check the error trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

In OnBindViewHolder

```
public static  boolean isPerformClicked;
int performClickCount;

 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    if (i==0){
        viewHolder.tv_android.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        if (performClickCount==0){
            isPerformClicked = true;
            viewHolder.itemView.performClick();
        }else{
            viewHolder.tv_android.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }

    }else{
        isPerformClicked=false;
        performClickCount = performClickCount+1;
        viewHolder.tv_android.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

    }
    if (i!=BlankFragment.selectedPosition){
        viewHolder.tv_android.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    }else{
        viewHolder.tv_android.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }

    viewHolder.tv_android.setText(android_versions.get(i).getAndroid_version_name());
    Picasso.with(context).load(android_versions.get(i).getAndroid_image_url()).resize(120, 60).into(viewHolder.img_android);
}
```

In holder Item Click or item

```
  @Override
public void onRecyclerViewItemClick(@NonNull View view, @NonNull AndroidVersion calendarDTO, int position) {
    selectedPosition=position;
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (!isPerformClicked){
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid using `public static`

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(null);
    if (position == 0) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 holder.itemView.performClick();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using interface in different activity..!

Comment: Try this code, I have edited it. change your own layout click event for holder.itemview.setOnClickListener

Comment: we need itself perform auto click, your code states that first manual click and then it perform autoclick..!

Comment: Yes..! it is not performing click events..!

Answer (score -1):

as per your discription you have to write context of toast in proper way, if you are in adapter then wite **context** and if you are in fragment or in activity then note down it as per your context.

Thank you...

Comment: The interface is in different activity. so I'm using "this" but the problem is different.

Comment: then set context as perameter and use it instead of this.. it is giving you the error.\

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling when notifydatasetChanged()

above line is the error..! and its not related to context or toast..!

Comment: The error because of notifydatasetChanged() method since it is calling before recyclerview completes laying down the items..!